# ./configure Permission Denied when try to build llvm

Tags: permissions, clang

I'm try to build to build Clang and LLVM and after download it I want to configure it so when I do that command :

```
../llvm/configure --prefix=/usr/clang_3_3 --enable-optimized --enable-targets=host
```

it's show me error configure permission Denied even when I'm root and I try

```
chmod +x
```

it didn't work any help

Note :
I download Clang and LLVM from svn and I put it to anthor dir(not the root) in /media one of these dirs

Comment: Are these files on an external hard disk? Try putting them in your `~` home directory instead.

Comment: I have no enough space

Comment: any other solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put it on a Linux file system. Microsoft Windows file-systems do not support setting the executable bit.

Try these workarounds:

- You could run it like (with `bash` in front, assuming it opens with bash)

  ```
  bash ../llvm/configure --prefix=/usr/clang_3_3 --enable-optimized --enable-targets=host
  ```
- You could create a small `ext4` partition on an external hard drive and put the files on there
- See here: [How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-to-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition)